# 1px difference in absolute positioning (Chrome/FF)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

A website I'm working on (URL in the comments) has a problem with the menu. It looks OK in Chrome if the `bottom` property of `#nav` is set to `2px`, but looks bad in FF and IE. If I set it to `3px`, it looks OK in FF and IE, but bad in Chrome.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: did you try CSS reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for Chrome/safari use hack

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
#nav { bottom: 2px !important; }
}
```

will work for you

Comment: Hack? :/ but I guess maybe it will be necessary. If nobody posts anything better I'll accept this.

Comment: yeah these are called browser hacks, check http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks

Comment: Yeah, I just don't like to use them :)

Comment: OK who cares about good practise, I'm gonna use this. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Browser @media hacks are one solution, but when you need cross-browser compatibility, you should use CSS reset, because all browsers have their default styles.  This have to be put in your style.css file before all your custom styles or include the cssreset.css file before your own styles.

You can find css reset here:  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

u can use browser detection using jquery and set the bottom value.and keep default value as 3px.

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $("#nav").css('bottom','2px');
  }
```